# change of variable in SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes

Here is the original question,
Suppose you have a call option on the square of a log-normal asset $V_t$. what equation does the price satisfy?

my question is how this corresponds to a change of variable  stated in the solution to this question.
in the original BS equation.[image]
solution gives,

since $V_t$ is also a log-normal process, The BS equation governs this process will be similar to that governs $S_t$ where $S_t$ is a standard log-normal process.

here is the full solution,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that by Ito if we set $F(s,t)=s^2$ we have
$$F_s(s,t)=2s,\,F_{ss}(s,t)=2$$
so
$$dF=\bigg(2r S_t^2+2\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S_t^2\bigg)dt+2\sigma S_t^2dW_t$$
$$\implies \frac{dF}{F}=(2r+\sigma^2)dt+2\sigma dW_t$$
So the PDE satisfied by a call option on such asset is
$$C_t(x,t)+x(2r+\sigma^2)C_x(x,t)+2\sigma^2x^2C_{xx}(x,t)=rC(x,t)$$
with terminal condition $C(x,T)=(x-K)^+$. To see that this corresponds to a change of variable in the original PDE, set $x=s^2$ obtaining
$$\begin{aligned}C_t(s,t)&=C_t(x,t)\\
C_s(s,t)&=2sC_x(x,t)\\
C_{ss}(s,t)&=2C_x(x,t)+4s^2C_{xx}(x,t)
\end{aligned}$$
Substituting these back into the Black-Scholes PDE you obtain the PDE above.